# Как сделать чтобы частицы в Unity не передвигались за объектами-родителями?

Tags: unity3d

Есть Particle System с частицами и объект-родитель. При движении объекта вылетающие частицы тянутся за ним, выходит не очень красиво. Как сделать, чтобы частицы не двигались за объектом, но из него вылетали?

Comment: `Simulation Space: Local`

Answer (score 1):

Надо поставить Simulation Space с local на world